# Logging on to Kerberos / Kerberos Constrained Delegation from a pc not in the domain

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

Can a client pc authenticate against a Kerberos / KCD authenticated service (that is - not use NTLM) if they have valid domain accounts, but the pc they're using can't access any of the DCs and / or isn't a member of the domain itself?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this strictly answers your question, but I see two points to be made here:

1. Can a user log on to the domain from a computer not joined to the domain? The answer is no, as far as I'm aware.
2. Can a user access domain resources from a computer not joined to the domain? The answer is yes.